# MVC4 .Net 4.5 User Role Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm updating my app from mvc4 asp.net4 to .net4.5 and user roles are not working.

currently i'm using this code

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
            GenericPrincipal userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
            Context.User = userPrincipal;
 //Or
//HttpContext.Current.User = userPrincipal;
        }
    }
```

I can add roles to current user with the help of above and check user role in controller 
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Guest")] or User.IsInRole("Admin")

but my code is not working in MVC4 ASP.Net 4.5

I don't want to use Role Provider. for e.g. Roles.CreateRole or Roles.AddUserToRole

Can someone please help me with this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can repro the issue even under MVC 4 .NET 4.0. Not sure why it doesn't repro under .NET 4.0 for you.

It looks like that even you replace the principal in Application_AuthenticateRequest. The principal will be finally replaced with System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal by simple membership code, and I believe the RolePrincipal will query database to get the user’s role data. Since you don't use RoleProvider, the RolePrincipal won’t contain any role data and it will get rid of the roles data from previous principal.

A possible workaround is to change Application_AuthenticateRequest to Application_AuthorizeRequest which happens after simple membership set RolePrincipal. 
BTW, you should set both HttpContext.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal to the same user.

Please let me know if the workaround above works for you.

Comment: Hi Hongye, Thanks for your help its working now, yes, you are right principal user role replaced by System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal and was trying to get role from database.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.5, GenericPrincipal now inherits from System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal; previously it inherited from System.Object.

Our application stores this in session (in database) but it seems to serialize and deserializes some of the claims internals differently as I ran into similar issues with roles missing.